# HttpClient.PostAsync and PHP api

Tags: c#, php, json, http, maui

Hello All respected SO members,

I am trying to build an `android` app with `.NET MAUI`.
I tried to save a content to `MySQL` database using `HttpClient.PostAsync` through PHP Api, however I can not make it work (the response is Success but the data is not saved to the table), while when I tried using POSTMAN to test with the `PHP` Api, everything is ok and it is able to save into the desired table.

`.NET MAUI` code

```
EmployeeData emp = new EmployeeData();
emp.emp_pin= EmpID.Text;

HttpClient cl = new HttpClient();
string js = JsonSerializer.Serialize(emp);
StringContent httpContent = new StringContent(js, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = cl.PostAsync(Url, httpContent).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    DisplayAlert("Success", "Success Record Your Data.", "OK");
}
else
{
    DisplayAlert("Fail", "Please Try Again.", "OK");
}
```

Model

```
public class EmployeeData
{
    public string emp_pin{ get; set; }
}
```

`PHP` API

```
<?php
require_once('dbhelper.php');

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$emppin=$data['emp_pin'];
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test (emp_pin) VALUES (?)");
$sql->bind_param('s', $emppin);
$sql->execute();
if ($sql) {
    echo json_encode(array('RESPONSE' => 'SUCCESS'));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('RESPONSE' => 'FAILED'));
}
```

Using POSTMAN, the data is successfully saved to the table.
[image]

using the JSON Visualizer,
[image]

Please highlight to me which part I made a mistake on.

Comment: You've provided no debugging info. Get PHP to log what it actually receives in the `$json` field. Get it to log any exceptions or errors, including SQL ones, and check for them. Debug the C# and see if `httpContent` contains what you're expecting or not. Give us a clue, in other words! Remember we can't necessarily run your code, or certainly not end-to-end anyway, so you need to narrow down the problem with some meaningful investigation, rather than just reporting the basic external symptoms and hoping someone else can guess. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue.

Comment: I would observe though, that `emp.emppin` will serialize as a property named `emppin` in the resulting JSON - demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ywjm0W . But in PHP you have written it to expect a property named `emp_pin`, and that is what you have sent from Postman. Therefore sending a JSON object to PHP with a different property name will cause PHP a problem - demo: https://3v4l.org/RWCUK. Doing some basic debugging - as I described above - would have made this obvious quite quickly, as would carefully reviewing and double-checking your work. Voting to close the question as a typo.

Comment: i have make a revision from `emppin` to `emp_pin` but it turn out that the response is not success now. and added the JSON visualizer from the js object.

Comment: Ok. So...do some more debugging on the PHP side now. We've eliminated one problem, now make sure you find out what the next issue is.

Comment: P.S. To make your error handling more robust (unless you're on PHP 8.1 or above where this is already enabled by default), add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. The `if ($sql) {` in your code should not be needed. You can just assume it's successful unless it throws an exception. And more importantly, if it throws an exception then you'll be able to see _why_ it failed, not just that it somehow failed!

Comment: @ADyson i am adding `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before `new mysqli()` as per your advice, 

and then i changed `var response = cl.PostAsync(Url, httpContent).Result;` to `var response = await cl.PostAsync(Url, httpContent);` and everything works now.

Thank you for your guidance and teaching to me to debug the error one by one as well as the new `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

BTW, how do i accept your answer?

Comment: Up to now I only wrote comments as suggestions, to see if they help. Now I wrote it up into a proper answer below, so you can accept it / vote for it if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`emp.emppin` will serialize as a property named emppin in the resulting JSON - demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ywjm0W . But in PHP you have written it to expect a property named `emp_pin`, and that is what you have sent from Postman. Therefore sending a JSON object to PHP with a different property name will cause PHP a problem - demo: https://3v4l.org/RWCUK

You can therefore rename the property in your C# class to make it match what PHP expects:

```
public class EmployeeData
{
    public string emp_pin{ get; set; }
}
```

Secondly, change

```
var response = cl.PostAsync(Url, httpContent).Result;
```

to

```
var response = await cl.PostAsync(Url, httpContent);
```